# How to manage long term episode in Deep Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I would like to know how to manage the problem of training a Deep Reinforcement Learning over long episode?

I need to manage a problem of a time series of 100 000 steps to achieve one episode. If my agent doesn't performed well, I consider game over and he starts at the beginning.

In DRL I use epsilon greedy decreasing with time. Naturally more the time run, less I have probabilities to explore (adding the fact that the agent often must starting at the beginning because of the first bad decisions). Nevertheless, for instance at certain moment (1000 time steps) I need to explore again at a large amount of time because my states have changed drastically.

My epsilon greedy strategy is not well suited for this kind of problem, I think I need more an exploration rate not indexed over time t but more over the state representation (is it a new state or not).

What do you think about it? Do you have any advices or research papers about this kind of approach?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

100k steps is quite uncommon in RL. [Mujoco tasks](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/__init__.py#L202) by default have 1k, while [Atari games](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/__init__.py#L581) have 10k, so that could be a good starting point. In particular, Montezuma's Revenge is known to be very challenging, as the player can easily die and not explore long enough to solve it. [Here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/montezumas-revenge) is a collection of papers with code about it.